# Codeigniter Bootstrap Alert not Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'm trying to make alert with cross sign. Unfortunately cross sign not working. I have included jquery before bootstrap.js. Here is my model. Thanks in Advance

```
public function create(){
    $data = array('name'=>  $this->input->post('name'));
        $this->db->insert('dbname', $data);
        echo'
          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>You have successfully posted
         </div>
       ';
        exit;
}
```

Comment: checked for any console errors?

Comment: Why don't you just return a bool value from server and display your static alert accordingly?

Comment: Trying this. But how to differentiate edit, update and delete.

Comment: pass some variable to controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to

```
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>You have successfully posted
```

this

```
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;You have successfully posted</a>
```

And as well as ***use Model to write data into database***. Use follows

**In controller**

```
public function create(){

    $this->load->model('Model_name');
    $result = $this->Model_name->insert_data();

    if($result == 1)
    {
        ?>
          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;You have successfully posted</a>
         </div>
         <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
          <div class="alert alert-error">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;Failed to poste</a>
         </div>
         <?php
    }


}
```

**In Model**

```
public function insert_data()
{
    $data = array(
    'name'=>  $this->input->post('name')
    );

    if(!$this->db->insert('dbname', $data))
    {
        return $log = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return $log = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your justification for the problem on the first instance is not correct.. A **[demo for your reference](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/00d2w0yz/1/)** If he keeps all the text inside `<a>` then whole thing will misalign.. `<a>` should have only `&times` i.e `x` or `close` text.. **[This is what he gets](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/00d2w0yz/2/)** when he does what you suggested..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao You may be correct sometime. But in Codeigniter we have to use like this

Comment: Sorry for that.. Am not much aware on that.. But html structures for bootstrap wouldn't change based on the development framework is what IMHO..

Comment: @Abdulla not working. Is it possible to write plain html in controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92127/discussion-between-nikolas-and-abdulla).

Comment: @nikolas happy to help :)

Comment: @nikolas always happy to help :)